# php - printf and sprintf have different outputs

Tags: php

I written the following tiny `php` program to test `printf` and `sprintf`:

```
<?php
    $str_1 = printf("%x%x%x", 65, 127, 245);
    $str_2 = sprintf("%x%x%x", 65, 127, 245);

    echo $str_1 . "\n";
    echo $str_2 . "\n";
```

the output is this:

```
417ff56
417ff5
```

why I have that 6 digit in the first line of output?

Comment: your `$str_1` contains a `"6"` - length returned by `printf`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**printf**](http://php.net/printf) doesnt return the string, it directly outputs it (and returns only its length). Try this

```
<?php
    printf("%x%x%x", 65, 127, 245);
    $str_2 = sprintf("%x%x%x", 65, 127, 245);
    echo "\n". $str_2 . "\n";
?>
```

**Output**

```
417ff5
417ff5
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/226035)**

Now you might ask why that extra 6 (in your output) then? Becuase printf returns the length of the printed string which is 6 in your case.

So here is how it goes

```
417ff56            // that extra 6 comes from your first echo.
417ff5
```

Answer (score 0):

**printf** :- directly print the formatted string.

**sprintf** :- convert given format and store values in a variable and you can use echo/print to print variable values.

```
$text = "65 127 245";
printf("%x%x%x", 65, 127, 245);
$str_2 = sprintf("%x%x%x", 65, 127, 245);
echo $str_2;
```