# Wrong format of post views count in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, return, echo

I print a line consisted of the post date and the number of views (use the plugin `wp-PostViews`). However, I get `26 [icon] 2016-01-09 [icon] views`, instead of `[icon] 2016-01-09 [icon] 26 views` (wrong position of the number of views) as shown below:

[image]

Here are the source codes:

```
$time_string_published = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
$time_string_published = sprintf( $time_string_published,
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ) )
);

printf( '<span class="posted-on">%1$s</span><span class="views-link">%2$s</span>',
                sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
                        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                        $time_string_published
                ),
                sprintf('%1$s views', the_views())
        );
```

The related css settings are:

```
.entry-meta .views-link:before {
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        font: normal 22px/1 'Genericons';
        vertical-align: top;
}
.entry-meta .views-link:before { content: '\f403'; }
```

BTW, the following codes work correctly, displaying as `[icon] 26` (the right position).

```
<span class="views-link">
      <?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { echo the_views(); } ?>
</span>
```

Is it possiable that the plugin `wp-PostViews` (contains the function `the_views()`) is loaded after excuting the above codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I tracked it. The reason is that the function `the_views()` prints something *directly*, instead return a variable. Here is the source code:

```
### Function: Display The Post Views
function the_views($display = true, $prefix = '', $postfix = '', $always = false) {
        $post_views = intval( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'views', true ) );
        $views_options = get_option('views_options');
        if ($always || should_views_be_displayed($views_options)) {
                $output = $prefix.str_replace( array( '%VIEW_COUNT%', '%VIEW_COUNT_ROUNDED%' ), array( number_format_i18n( $post_views ), postviews_round_number( $post_views) ), stripslashes( $views_options['template'] ) ).$postfix;
                if($display) {
                        echo apply_filters('the_views', $output);
                } else {
                        return apply_filters('the_views', $output);
                }
        }
        elseif (!$display) {
                return '';
        }
}
```

To solve it, **pass the parameter `false` to `the_views` to return as a variable, i.e., `the_views(false)`**.

```
 printf( '<span class="posted-on">%1$s</span><span class="views-link">%2$s</span>',
                sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
                        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                        $time_string_published
                ),
                sprintf('%1$s views', the_views(false))
        );
```

Comment: Glad you found it!  Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about anyone else - but this seems a bit like overkill on trying to do this.  Why not try:

```
$url = esc_url( get_permalink() );
$time = $time_string_published;
$views = the_views();

$out = <<<EOD
<span class="posted-on"><a href="$url"
rel="bookmark">$time</a></span><span class="views-link">$views</span>
EOD;

printf( "%s", $out );
```

The above does the same thing but is a bit clearer. Sorry!  Thought I had it but I got it wrong originally.  I've now corrected the generated code.  So NOW I say - have you checked what $time_string_published is giving you?

BTW: If your echo of the_views() is giving you "ico 26 views" why not just do this:

```
$views = substr( the_views(), 4 );
```

To get the "26 views" part.  It would then automatically have the "views" stuck on the end of it.  Just an idea.

Update : 8:57pm

Here is the reworked code.  It works for me.

```
<?php

$time_string_published = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
$time_string_published = sprintf( $time_string_published,
        date( 'c', time() ),
        date( 'Y-m-d', time() )
);

printf( '<span class="posted-on">%1$s</span><span class="views-link">%2$s</span>',
                sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
                        ( get_permalink() ),
                        $time_string_published
                ),
                sprintf('%1$s views', the_views())
        );

$date1 = date('c', time() );
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', time() );
$time_string_published = "<time class='entry-date published' datetime='$date1'>$date2</time>";

$url = get_permalink();
$view = the_views();

$s = "<a href='$url' rel='bookmark'>$time_string_published</a>";
echo "<p><span class='posted-on'>$s</span> <span class='views-link'>$view views</span>";

function get_permalink()
{
    return "http://www.google.com";
}
function the_views()
{
    return 26;
}

?>
```

The output is:

```
2016-01-1226 views

2016-01-12 26 views
```

And the page source code is:

```
<span class="posted-on"><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2016-01-12T02:55:41+00:00">2016-01-12</time></a></span><span class="views-link">26 views</span><p><span class='posted-on'><a href='http://www.google.com' rel='bookmark'><time class='entry-date published' datetime='2016-01-12T02:55:41+00:00'>2016-01-12</time></a></span> <span class='views-link'>26 views</span>
```

Note that the second line has a space between the first SPAN and the second one.  If you don't get the same output then there is something going on with either WordPress or some other part of the overall program.  About all the help I can provide. :-)

Comment: `$time_string_published` is correct (I added it to the question). I modified a wordpress theme.

Comment: Sorry - left off the printf() function.  By the way - I've seen printf muck up before when used with sprintf.  I think they sometimes interefere with each other.

Comment: is there a problem with css settings, like `float`?

Comment: is it possiable that the plugin `wp-postviews` (contains the function `the_views()`) is loaded after excuting the above codes?

Comment: All plugins should have already been loaded before you attempt to execute any Javascript unless you are doing it on-the-fly.  (ie:You load and go along the way.)  To ensure the entire document is loaded before you execute anything, you should be using the document.ready() function found in jQuery.  On the PHP side - all of your includes/requires should come BEFORE you try to use something.  If that "something" isn't there it would error off when you tried to use it.

Comment: I just saw this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120684/php-printf-and-sprintf-have-different-outputs?rq=1.  Note the output?  This is like your problem.  What is happening there is that PRINTF prints things one way and SPRINTF prints them another.  So even though YOU are putting them in the correct order - how PHP handles them makes them do what you are experiencing. In the link, what is happening is PRINTF triggers first and make $str_1 = 6 (the length of the string). So when the ECHO is gotten to, the string is already printed and the value of $str_1 is then tacked onto the end.

Comment: In your case, the problem is that PRINTF and SPRINTF also operate differently.  So I'd have to guess that PRINTF, SPRINTF, and ECHO all operate in different ways to achieve the final end (which is to get the output you need).  Especially putting one call inside of another.  I never do that or rather I only do that for mathematical formulaes.  Output I always try to keep separate.  Get everything ready to be output and then just do the output and stick with either PRINTF or ECHO - not both.

Comment: I tried your codes, but the issue still exists. It seems that the issue is not related to `sprintf` and/or `printf` (that might be the reason for downvotes).

Comment: I looked at your code again.  I must have missed the first few lines because I don't remember having seen them.  The "<time..." part you can make a lot simpler also.  I also do not know why you are using the "%1$s" stuff.  in both PRINTF and SPRINTF, when they encounter a "%" it means you want to format something but you are doing a get_the_date() function which gives you a date and you are using that.  Usually you see "%1s" which means one character. Can you make a Fiddle and use dummy values or post the actual output that is generated?  That might give me a better clue to work with.  Thx.

Comment: I posted in my original answer the reworked code.  Try it out. :-)

Comment: thx a lot. Finally, I tracked it. The reason is that the function `the_views` prints something *directly*, instead return a variable.